# Debug в eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, отладка

Недавно обновил eclipse, tomcat с 7 на 8, начал пользоваться maven(вместо ant) на новом проекте(всё перечислил, т.к. не знаю в чём дело). Проблема в том, что web приложение запускается и работает нормально, а вот в режиме debug никак.

```
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available
Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Comment: Напишите что у вас за приложение. Запостите конфиг логгера, если он у вас сконфигурирован.

Comment: при запуске каждого приложения создается "run configuration" или же "debug configuration" ( menu Run --> Run Configurations or menu Run --> Debug Configurations) попробуйте удалить существующий дебаг конфиг. В старых версиях эклипса часто из-за этого были проблемы. 

p.s. для того чтоб определить в чем проблема нужно больше информации